# Python: merge adjacent number in list

Tags: python, list

is it possible to merge the numbers in a list of chars?

I have a list with some characters:

```
my_list = ['a', 'f', '£', '3', '2', 'L', 'k', '3']
```

I'm want to concatenate the adjacent numbers as follow:

```
my_list = ['a', 'f', '£', '32', 'L', 'k', '3']
```

I have this, and it works fine, but i don't really like how it came out.

```
def number_concat(my_list):
    new_list = []
    number = ""

    for ch in my_list:
        if not ch.isnumeric():
            if number != "":
                new_list.append(number)
                number =""
            new_list.append(ch)            
        else:
            number = ''.join([number,ch])

    if number != "":
        new_list.append(number)

    return new_list
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: well what did you try? did it work or not?

Comment: Most programming questions which begin "is it possible" have a "yes" answer.

Comment: does this apply to `n` numbers in a row? how should that look when it is 3 numbers in a row, or say 4?

Comment: Loop the list with a `for` loop, check if the element can be a number, if yes, save in a temp list, if the next can be a number, then join them, if not, clear the temp list. This is of course, one way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a variable to track the index position in the list and then just compare two elements and if they are both digits concat them by popping the index and adding it to the previous one. we leave index pointing to the same value since we popd all other elements iwll have shifted so we need to check this index again and check the next char which will now be in that index. If the char is not a digit then move the index to the next char.

```py
# coding: latin-1
my_list = ['a', 'f', '£', '3', '2', 'L', 'k', '3']
index = 1
while index < len(my_list):
    if my_list[index].isdigit() and my_list[index - 1].isdigit():
        my_list[index - 1] += my_list.pop(index)
    else:
        index += 1

print(my_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['a', 'f', '£', '32', 'L', 'k', '3']
```

Comment: You can eliminate the extra variable if you use a reverse for-loop: `for index in range(len(my_list) - 1, 0, -1)`. Then it's only three lines.

Comment: How would the cases happen where you need to look at the same index again?

Comment: When you work forwards, the elements ahead all move down when an item is popped. But when you work backwards, only the elements *behind* move down, so the indexes ahead never change. Try it!

Comment: ah yeah i see what you mean now. Nice

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = ['a', 'f', '£', '3', '2', 'L', 'k', '3']

out = []
for _, g in groupby(enumerate(my_list, 2), lambda k: True if k[1].isdigit() else k[0]):
    out.append(''.join(val for _, val in g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'f', '£', '32', 'L', 'k', '3']
```

Comment: Or `k[1].isdigit() or k[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
>>> re.findall('\d+|.', ''.join(my_list))
['a', 'f', '£', '32', 'L', 'k', '3']
```

itertools:

```
>>> [x for d, g in groupby(my_list, str.isdigit) for x in ([''.join(g)] if d else g)]
['a', 'f', '£', '32', 'L', 'k', '3']
```

Another:

```
>>> [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(my_list, lambda c: c.isdigit() or float('nan'))]
['a', 'f', '£', '32', 'L', 'k', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

sure! this will combine all consecutive digits:

```
i = 0
while i < len(my_list):
  if my_list[i].isdigit():
    j = 1
    while i+j < len(my_list) and my_list[i+j].isdigit():
      my_list[i] += my_list.pop(i+j)
      j += 1
  i += 1
```

you can also do this recursively, which is maybe more elegant (in that it will be easier to build up correctly as the task becomes more complicated) but also possibly more confusing:

```
def group_digits(list, accumulator=None):
  if list == []:
     return accumulator or []
  if not accumulator:
     return group_digits(list[1:], list[:1])

  x = list.pop(0)
  if accumulator[-1].isdigit() and x.isdigit():
    accumulator[-1] += x
  else:
    accumulator.append(x)
  return group_digits(list, accumulator)
```

Comment: This doesn't remove elements that were combined into the previous element.

Comment: yep, meant to type pop() in there. fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You are just trying to *reduce* your numbers together.

One way to accomplish this is to loop through the list, and check if it's a number using [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric).

```
my_list = ['a', 'f', '£', '3', '2', 'L', 'k', '3']

new_list = ['']
for c in my_list:
  if c.isnumeric() and new_list[-1].isnumeric():  # Check if current and previous character is a number
    new_list[-1] += c                             # Mash characters together.
  else:
    new_list.append(c)
else:
  new_list[:] = new_list[1:]                      # Remove '' placeholder to avoid new_list[-1] IndexError

print(new_list)  # ['a', 'f', '£', '32', 'L', 'k', '3']
```

This has also been tested with first character is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way under the assumption that the non-numeric characters are not white-space:

```
''.join(c if c.isdigit() else ' '+ c + ' ' for c in my_list).split()
```

The idea is to pad with spaces the characters that you *don't* want merged, smush the resulting characters together so that the non-padded ones become adjacent, and then split the result on white-space, the net result leaving the padded characters unchanged and the non-padded characters joined.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a beginner-friendly solution using an index and two lists:

```
my_list = ['a', 'f', '£', '3', '2', 'L', 'k', '3']

result = []
index = 0
for item in my_list:
    if item.isdigit():
        # If current item is a number
        if my_list[index-1].isdigit() and len(result) > 1:
        # If previous item is a number too and it is not the 1st item 
        # of the list, sum the two and put them in the previous slot in result
            result[index-1] = my_list[index-1] + my_list[index]
        else:
            result.append(item)
    else:
        result.append(item)
    index += 1

print(my_list)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'f', '£', '3', '2', 'L', 'k', '3']
['a', 'f', '£', '32', 'L', 'k', '3']
```